# React Native Expo Build failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, build, expo

I have an error when I try building my react native project with eas, but it works with expo.

```
Error: The resource `/home/expo/workingdir/build/index.js` was not found.
    at /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/metro/src/IncrementalBundler.js:457:26
    at gotStat (node:fs:2637:21)
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED
[stderr] error The resource `/home/expo/workingdir/build/index.js` was not found.
[stderr] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[stderr] * What went wrong:
[stderr] Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
[stderr] > Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
[stderr] * Try:
[stderr] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[stderr] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[stderr] BUILD FAILED in 1m 50s
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.9/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
34 actionable tasks: 34 executed
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. Please see logs for the "Run gradlew" phase.
```

Comment: where is `/home/expo/workingdir/build/index.js` being referred in your code?

Comment: @RebecaRose Were you able to fix this problem? I am also running into a similar problem. I am using yarn workspaces for monorepo. I started seeing this after I upgraded from react-native 0.66.0 to 0.68.2. For me, it is saying "/Users/username/Projects/app-monorepo/index.js" when it should be looking at "/Users/username/Projects/app-monorepo/packages/app/index.js" because that is where the index.js file lies.

Comment: Please check this https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/363

Answer (score 0):

You should check you package.json and rename index.js to your entry file.

```
},
  "main": "index.js"
}
```